# ATI x1400 12.04 OS cannot see that it is a sepparate video card

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati

Ubuntu not only can NOT see that it is not a "vga compatible device" but when trying to install propietary drivers, AMD installer asks to use the --iscurrentdistro (cant find in google how to use this switch) for install.  need assistance, tried running google earth and it really looks software rendered using fglrx

thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Ati have dropped support for your graphics card in the current binary driver which leaves you with the open-source drivers that come with Ubuntu to do most of the work...  This has happened before with a friends pc and Ati's own binary driver just didn't want to work on his current setup...